# Menubar created by PyQt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qmenubar

i designed in PyQt-Designer a surface and converted it to a .py
No I´m trying to link a function to a menubar-(button). There is something like open, save, close.... 
I have tried a lot, but unsuccessfully, i hope you can help me to connect a simple function to the open-button in the menu bar.

for example a function that is linked to the menubar
menubar->open->function(open_path):

```
def open_path():
                root= Tk()
                Pfad=askdirectory()
                root.destroy
```

Thank you for your help!

Here is the Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("Auswertung Brechzahlbestimmung")
        MainWindow.resize(1205, 641)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.histogram = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.histogram.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(182, 126))
        self.histogram.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 126))
        self.histogram.setObjectName("histogram")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.histogram)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_4, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.seitenansicht = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.seitenansicht.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(537, 407))
        self.seitenansicht.setObjectName("seitenansicht")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.seitenansicht, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalSlider.setObjectName("verticalSlider")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.verticalSlider, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.draufsicht = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.draufsicht.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(537, 407))
        self.draufsicht.setObjectName("draufsicht")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.draufsicht, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.referenz = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.referenz.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.referenz.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.referenz.setObjectName("referenz")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.referenz, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_5.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

#Here begins the Menubar

        self.menubar =  QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1205, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuDatei = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuDatei.setObjectName("menuDatei")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)


        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")

        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionExport_Picture = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExport_Picture.setObjectName("actionExport_Picture")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit") 

        self.menuDatei.addAction(self.actionSave)

        self.menuDatei.addAction(self.actionOpen)

        self.menuDatei.addSeparator()
        self.menuDatei.addAction(self.actionExport_Picture)
        self.menuDatei.addSeparator()   
        self.menuDatei.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuDatei.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Auswertung Brechzahlbestimmung"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Schnitt"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Draufsicht"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "n"))
        self.menuDatei.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Datei"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionExport_Picture.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export Picture"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend you read [the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), it recommends not to modify the class generated by Qt Designer, but you must create another class that inherited from a widget and use the class provided by Qt Designer as an interface.

On the other hand it is not necessary to use tkinter, Qt provides widgets to obtain directory paths like QFileDialog.

And finally you have to use the triggered signal of self.actionOpen.

Considering the above the solution is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def open_file(self):
        fdirectory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Open Directory")
        if fdirectory:
            print(fdirectory)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! now i understand the procedure :) It helped and worked for me!

Comment: Do you also know, how i can simply add a image to one of the QGraphicwView after opening the path?

Comment: @D.Stang Use `your_graphics_view.scene().addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(filename))`, but you must first set a scene in the QGraphicsView in the constructor : 
 `scene = QtWidgets.QGraphiscScene(your_graphics_view)` `your_graphics_view.setScene(scene)`